# Android: How to set List item checked?

Tags: android, list, checkbox, adapter

I have an android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice with checkboxes an want so initiate some of them. 
How can I do that?
I have the following code:

```
    private void fillList() {
    Cursor NotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(NotesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECKED };

    int[] to = new int[] { 
    android.R.id.text1, 
    android.R.id.text2, 
    //How set checked or not checked?
     };

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, NotesCursor,
            from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);

}
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html
Does not help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the resource id of your checkbox in your row layout into the `to` array, corresponding to the `NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECKED` cursor in `from` array.
2. Implement a [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html).
3. Have the [ViewBinder.setViewValue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29) method check for when its called for the `NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECKED` column.
4. When it is *not* the KEY_CHECKED column, have it return `false` the the adapter will do what it normally does.
5. When it is the KEY_CHECKED column, have it set the CheckBox view (cast required) to checked or not as you wish and then return `true`so that adapter won't attempt to bind it itself.  The cursor and corresponding column id is available to access query data to determine whether to check the checkbox or not.
6. Set your ViewBinder in your SimpleCursorAdapter via [setViewBinder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29)

Here's one of my ViewBinder implementations.  Its not for checboxes, rather its for doing some fancy formatting of a text view, but it should give you some idea for the approach:

```
private final SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder mViewBinder =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(
                final View view,
                final Cursor cursor,
                final int columnIndex) {
            final int latitudeColumnIndex =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        LocationDbAdapter.KEY_LATITUDE);
            final int addressStreet1ColumnIndex =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        LocationDbAdapter.KEY_ADDRESS_STREET1);

            if (columnIndex == latitudeColumnIndex) {

                final String text = formatCoordinates(cursor);
                ((TextView) view).setText(text);
                return true;

            } else if (columnIndex == addressStreet1ColumnIndex) {

                final String text = formatAddress(cursor);
                ((TextView) view).setText(text);
                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```