# Android - adding photos taken by the user into a listview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-listview, simpleadapter, listview-adapter

I currently have a simple list view adapter that holds two rows of text. What I am trying to do next is add the option of displaying a photo that the user took in the list view. I modified my list adapter like so:

```
standardAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.post_layout,
                new String[] { "time", "post", "image"}, new int[] {
                        R.id.postTimeTextView, R.id.postTextView, R.id.post_imageView});
```

Then I add it to the hash map as usual and refresh the adapter:

```
// create a new hash map with the text from the post
        feedPostMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        feedPostMap.put("time", currentTimePost);
        feedPostMap.put("post", post);
        if(photoWasTaken == 1){
            feedPostMap.put("image", pictureTaken);
        }
        //add map to list
        list.add(feedPostMap);

        // refresh the adapter
        standardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Lastly, here is the code for activity on result:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "ON activity for result- CAMERA");
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //get and decode the file
            pictureTaken = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/livefeedrTemp.png");

            //Display picture above the text box
            imageViewShowPictureTaken.setImageBitmap(pictureTaken);
            displayPhotoLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

            //NEW - make photo variable = 1
            photoWasTaken = 1;
        }
    }
```

However I am running into an issue. The photo, in bitmap form, is not being added to the list view. It just appears as empty white space. Am I doing something wrong here? Secondly, if the user decided not to take a picture, then the image view should not be displayed. I'm not sure how to implement this. Should I create a custom list adapter?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the size of the picture, you  should maybe tried to transform the picture into a thumbnail.

Comment: I just tried creating a thumbnail from my image and adding it and its still not displaying

Comment: When you access your picture on the sdcard, you should access it by using this.getExternalStorageDirectory()+pathToImage, and not directly by /sdcard/.
You should also check you have permission to access for read/write on the external storage in your manifest.xml,and, if you could provide some error code, or some logcat it could be relevant here, because the process you use seems to be right, but I can't really test the code right now.

Comment: That's the problem because I am not getting any error codes whatsoever. Permissions as good, and the image is already stored into my pictureTaken bitmap variable (i display it to the user before it is added to the listview). I think the issue is that it is not a resource bmp, instead one that is created and may be replaced later. I've tried accessing the imageview directly but you cant access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that SimpleAdapter don't support Bitmaps by default.

> By default, the value will be treated as an image resource. If the
>   value cannot be used as an image resource, the value is used as an
>   image Uri.

There is a solution, however. You can set a custom [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html) and make the binding by yourself.

```
class MyViewBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
        if (view instanceof ImageView && data instanceof Bitmap) {
            ImageView v = (ImageView)view;
            v.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)data);
            // return true to signal that bind was successful
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And set this to your SimpleAdapter:

`adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());`

This way every time the SimpleAdapter tries to bind a value to a View it first calles your View binder's setViewValue method. If it returns false, it tries to bind it itself.

---

You can also try to put into your map an URL as a string pointing to the sd card location. I'm not sure however, that the SimpleAdapter can handle this.

---

Also see this post:
[Dynamically show images from resource/drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885469/dynamically-show-images-from-resource-drawable)

Comment: Thanks bbalazs for your answer! this is really interesting. i will try to implement this now and respond with my observations.